# Is there a way in pentaho to put variable in the select value step?

Tags: pentaho

Can I define inside a "select value step" a variable?
like ${column_name}

How can I make it work, I have a parameter that will change this column every time.

Comment: I think, without sharing your transformation it will difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check the box in the step select values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That step doesn't allow using variables to select the columns of the stream you want to keep.
In this case you could use Metadata Injection, read Pentaho documentation as well as study the example in the samples folder of your installation on how to use Metadata Injection.